# Get only chflags from terminal

Tags: macos

I am wondering if there is a way to get only the chflags of a given file.

As of now, I can only manage to view chflags using:

```
ls -lO
```

which would return something along the lines of:

```
dr-x------  8 User  staff  uchg        272 Aug  9 14:15 File
```

If possible, is there a way to get only the chflags as text in the same way that you can view exclussively chmod values with:

```
stat -f %A
```

Thanks!

Edit:

Upon looking further, there is a stat field specifier:

```
stat -f %f File
```

that does tell one how many flags a file has, but gives no more detail. Can anyone expand on this?

Comment: Been thru the man pages, doesn't appear to be a way using a shell.  Maybe there is a library in another language (C, Python, etc.) for accessing these flags?  You could also use sed/awk/cut/etc to get what you want with the `ls` command, but that is prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

`stat -f "%f" file` returns the file flags as a decimal number. The file- `/usr/include/sys/stat.h` defines file flags in hexadecimal numbers. You could use `stat -f "%Xf" file` to produce a hexadecimal number. A script or shell function that parses the flag field from `ls -lOd file` would be the simplest solution.